# Setting environment variables before exec'ing

Tags: c, macos, process, operating-system

I am doing a fork and then a execvpe on the child process to execute a command with some environment variables needed by the command. This is ok when I am on Linux.

Enter Mac Os and I do not find this system call. Instead it offers 'execle', but then it takes the command args as 'varargs', which I cannot use since my arguments are stored in a vector and could not find a way to use 'execle' with that.

The other option that I am having is to, set the environment variables after before calling 'execvp'  using 'setenv'. Is there any security concern or incorrectness in general with this approach ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no security concern, but this variable will be visible to parent process as well. Something to remember.

Comment: @SergeyA I am doing setenv in the child process after fork.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, that's exactly what I am doing for Mac OS.